# NULL Pointer exception for sending html mail using Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

**Spring-Mail.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />


    <property name="javaMailProperties">
       <props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="mailMail" class="com.mkyong.common.EmailProcessor">
    <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

**EmailProcessor.java**

eBeanFactory@7e78d6c6: defining beans [mailSender,mailMail]; root of factory hierarchy
    java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: what is line 56 in EmailProcessor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;`

You have to call the setter of this property In your case 
 `private MailSender mailSender;` will be automatically injected by spring. But 
 `private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;` will be null.

And you are calling `javaMailSender.send(mimeMessage);` resulting in null pointer.

Use `(JavaMailSender)mailSender.send(mimeMessage);` instead of `javaMailSender.send(mimeMessage);`

Comment: Doesn't he do that in the bean definition of `mailMail`?

Comment: he is setting mailSender in bean definition, not javaMailSender

Comment: Subin thanks for ur reply.i am new to spring n how to call the setter of this property private MailSender mailSender.can u explain with example..

Comment: @JagathesewarenKuppuraj why dont you try using `mailSender.send(mimeMessage);` instead of `javaMailSender.send(mimeMessage);`

Comment: cant send html mail using mailSender.send(mimeMessage);  we can send text mail only using mailSender.send(simpleMailMessage);

Comment: OK , then you should cast it to `JavaMailSender` and invoke send(mimeMessage);. Just use `(JavaMailSender)mailSender.send(mimeMessage);` since mailSender is an instance of JavaMailSenderImpl, cast is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Go through the below link You can send the mail easily
http://javaeasyforu.blogspot.in/2013/10/sending-email-using-spring-mvc.html

Comment: Thanks Karthik that link is very useful